# how can i make python socket listen after one client disconnect?

Tags: python, sockets

My server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
port = 12345
while True:
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ("Socket Up and running with a connection from",addr)
    while True:
        rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode()
        print("S:",rcvdData)
        c.send(rcvdData.encode())
        if(sendData == "Bye" or sendData == "bye"):
            break
    c.close()
```

My client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',12345))
while True:
    str = input("S: ")
    s.send(str.encode());
    if(str == "Bye" or str == "bye"):
        break
    print ("N:",s.recv(1024).decode())
s.close()
```

I have read to try to add try/except but im not sure where should i add that. Sorry for my english.
I want to accept connections even if no one is waiting to be accepted.

Comment: Nominally you want to keep calling `s.accept()` to accept more clients. Exception handlers should protect from errors between accept calls... unless they are legitimate "kill the server" type bugs. You could create a thread per accepted socket. You could use `select` (or poll or epoll) to run all connections in a single thread. You could use the new async services of python. You could use a higher level abstraction like zeromq. There are too many options to really give a definitive answer here. Mostly likely examples and tutorials from these options would show you how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple client connections are handled by calling `accept`, once per client. Nominally, you could just add a while loop plus exception handling to manage the connections:

```
import socket
import struct

s = socket.socket()
port = 12345
while True:
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ("Socket Up and running with a connection from",addr)
        try:
            while True:
                rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode()
                print("S:",rcvdData)
                c.send(rcvdData.encode())
                if(sendData == "Bye" or sendData == "bye"):
                    break
        except (OSError, socket.error) as e:
            print("Error:", e)
            # reset connection
            c.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
            c.close()
        else:
            c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            c.close()
```

This will only allow a single client connection at at time. If you want to handle multiple connections at once, there are a hundred ways to do it and that's beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: I tried this and i deleted the if(sendData) thing but when i close connection i cant reconnect